# Combine two table with different column name using Union all

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables T1 and T2 with column name proj in T1 and projectID in T2. I have to combine these two tables using Union all. As both column has similar kind of information. How it can done so that it is visible under one column name

Comment: See here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Actually answer given by everyone is correct. I heart fully thank you ppl for your kind gesture. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the datatype are same ,the column names for a UNION result set are taken from the column names of the first SELECT statement.

SELECT proj as project FROM T1 UNION ALL
SELECT projectID FROM T2

Answer (score 2):

You could select the required fields in the right order and give this particular field an alias to avoid confusion later.

```
SELECT col1, col2... , proj as Project from T1
UNION ALL 
SELECT col1, col2..., project_ID as Project from T2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT proj as Project
FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT projectID as Project
FROM T2
```